# What is the meaning of »Aha-Erlebnis«?

Tags: meaning

I already searched in dictionnaries but I never found the meaning of it.

Answer (score 15):

An [Aha-Erlebnis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aha-Erlebnis) is a term from psychology, describing the sudden insight in a previously pondered, but unsolved problem.

English terms are [eureka effect, aha! or eureka moment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_effect), the "eureka" going back to the legend of [Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes), who allegedly sat in his bath when he realized how to solve the question of the forged crown and ran through the streets exclaiming "Eureka!" ("I found it!").